# The number of transpositions in $S_n$ divides the cardinal of the conjugacy class of any odd permutation

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

I was wondering if there is an elegant (or not so elegant) proof of the following:

> There is an $n_0$ (possibly equal to one) such that for any $n\geq n_0$ the number of transpositions in $S_n$ divides the cardinal of the conjugacy class of any odd permutation.

Edit: The context of this is not very relevant. In any case, I want to prove that there is a positive linear combination of any irreducible character of $S_n$ evaluated at the odd conjugacy classes that equals zero (different from the trivial and signature characters). I know how to prove this but I would like to divide by the cardinal of the conjugacy class of a transposition to have as coefficient one in that term, the problem is that I would like to keep the coefficients in $\mathbb{N}$.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I have tested this before posting the question, this is true for $n=1,\dots,7$ and it seems that it is "evidently" true as $n$ grows. Unfortunately I am not able to prove this by induction. Also, I don't understand why I have a downvote, I cannot find any reference to this and I find it quite interesting! Should I have posted something different?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I have added context, but I don't think it is relevant. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Yes sorry - comment deleted.

Comment: Note that the result does not hold for all classes of involutions (e.g., Sym(8)) so one cannot simply use the fact that all odd elements have even order and so power to an involution. (Also, this is true up to $n=20$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an attempt at a proof (for all values of $n$), but it is not very elegant I am afraid! Any improvements would be welcome.

Since the number of transpositions is $n(n-1)/2$, we need to trove that the $|C_G(\sigma)|$ divides $2(n-2)!$ for an odd permutation $\sigma \in S_n$.

Odd permutations have an odd number of cycles of even length, so there exists an even $r$ and odd $t$ such that $\sigma$ has exactly $t$ cycles of length $r$. So we can write $\sigma=\sigma_1\sigma_2$, where $\sigma_1$ consists of the cycles of length $r$, and $\sigma_2$ the remaining cycles.
Then $C_G(\sigma) = C_{S_{tr}}(\sigma_1) \times C_{S_{n-tr}}(\sigma_2)$, so it is sufficient to prove the result in the case $\sigma = \sigma_1$.

So $n=tr$ and $\sigma$ consists of $t$ cycles of length $r$, and its centralizer $C_G(\sigma)$ is a wreath product $ C_{r} \wr S_t$, which has order $r^tt!$.

Now if $r>4$, then $S_{r-2}$ has a subgroup $H$ of order $r$, and so $S_{t(r-2)}$ has a subgroup $H \wr S_t$ of order $r^tt!$, so this divides $(r-2)t! \le (rt-2)!= (n-2)!$ and we are done.

So we just have to handle the cases $r=2$ and $r=4$.

Write $r^tt! = 2^km$ with $m$ odd. Then $m$ divides $t!$ and $t \le n-2$, so it remains to prove that $2^k$ divides $2(n-2)!$.

Now $2^k$ = $r^t2^j$ where $2^j$ divides $(t-1)!$.

When $r=2$, since $C_r \wr S_{t-1} \le S_{n-2}$, we have $r^{t-1}2^j$ divides $(n-2)!$, so $r^t2^j$ divides $2(n-2)!$ as claimed.

When $r=4$, we have $C_r \wr S_{t-1} \le S_{n-4}$, so $r^{t-1}2^j$ divides $(n-4)!$, and again $r^t2^j$ divides $2(n-2)!$.

Comment: For the non-algebriaists, like me, it would be nice to put the name of "wreath product" explicitly, otherwise one has to do an inverse search with the latex symbol. (I have learned what it is now, thanks for the answer!)

Comment: OK, point taken. I guess I was thinking that any approach to this problem is likely to involve centralizers of permutations in $S_n$, and the description of these centralizers involves wreath products, so it is difficult to get anywhere without understanding the concept.